# monacaのmaster-detailテンプレートにng-controllerを追加すると表示が崩れる

Tags: monaca, angularjs

初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、ご教授お願いいたします。

monacaでアプリ製作を考えています。
monacaの「master-detail」テンプレートを元にプロジェクトを作成しようと思っています。

データバインディングの観点からng-controllerを記述したいのですが、

`<ons-page>` に `ng-controller="newCtrl"` と記述し、
iPhoneのmonacaデバッガーで確認したところ、表示が崩れてしまい
クリックで詳細ページに飛ぶこともできません。

`<ons-page>` を `<div>` でくくり、 `<div ng-controller="newCtrl">` としても結果は同じでした。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script>
    ons.bootstrap();

  </script>
  <style>
    .item {
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    .item-thum {
      background-color: #ccc;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .item-title {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    .item-desc {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #666;
      line-height: 1.3;
      margin: 4px 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    }
    .item-label {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #999;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>    

  <ons-navigator page="list.html" var="app.navi"></ons-navigator>

  <ons-template id="list.html">
    <ons-page id="list-page" ng-controller="newctrl">
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Master Details</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-list>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">Item Title</span>
                <span class="item-label">4h</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">Another Item Title</span>
                <span class="item-label">6h</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">Yet Another Item Title</span>
                <span class="item-label">1day ago</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="detail.html">
    <ons-page id="detail-page">

      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">Details</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-list modifier="inset" style="margin-top: 10px">
        <ons-list-item class="item">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">Title</span>
                <span class="item-label">Foobar</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">desc</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" id="add-note-action" class="add-note-action-item">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-chatboxes" fixed-width="true" style="color: #ccc"></ons-icon>
          Add a note
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>

      <ons-list style="margin-top: 10px">
        <ons-list-item class="item">
          <header>
            <span class="item-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
          </header>
          <p class="item-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="item">
          <header>
            <span class="item-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
          </header>
          <p class="item-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="item">
          <header>
            <span class="item-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
          </header>
          <p class="item-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>

      <br>

    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

</body>

</html>
```

理想はng-controllerの記述をしても表示が崩れない、クリックが機能することです。
解決策ご教授いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ヘッダーをこんな感じにしてあげたらうまくいくんじゃないかと思います。

```
<script>
  ons.bootstrap()
  .controller('newCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageTitle = "Page Title";
  });
</script>
```

一応サンプルです（detailの遷移はできなかったので見やすくするために端折ってます）。
※ここではdetailへの遷移は再現できませんでしたが、デバッガでは確認できました。

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      ons.bootstrap()
      .controller('newCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageTitle = "Master Details";
      });
    </script>
  <style>
    .item {
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    .item-thum {
      background-color: #ccc;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .item-title {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    .item-desc {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #666;
      line-height: 1.3;
      margin: 4px 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    }
    .item-label {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #999;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>    

  <ons-navigator page="list.html" var="app.navi"></ons-navigator>

  <ons-template id="list.html">
    <ons-page id="list-page" ng-controller="newCtrl">
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">{{pageTitle}}</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-list>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">Item Title</span>
                <span class="item-label">4h</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">Another Item Title</span>
                <span class="item-label">6h</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">Yet Another Item Title</span>
                <span class="item-label">1day ago</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="detail.html">
    <ons-page id="detail-page">
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

</body>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通りにヘッダーに追加したら正しく表示することができました。 controllerの定義（？）も入れてやらないと表示が崩れてしまうということなのでしょうか？
もう少し勉強しますm(_ _)m ご教授ありがとうございました！